# Toolbar does not fill menu area width

Tags: java, android

I've created a menu with a width of 150dp. The toolbar does not match the width of the app. so that the area under the navbar icon is unfilled.
[Current toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E1Wf.png)
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTeMt.png)

custom_toolbar.xml

```
    <Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- text -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This text is underneath"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

        <!-- Container for the rest of the screen - Below the Toolbar -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Questions

1. Why is the toolbar not filling the whole area? How can I fix this?
2. Can I use something other than a fixed 150dp size to set the height of the navbar? (such as a percentage)

Comment: Does your toolbar have any parent layout?

Comment: The toolbar does not have a parent layout. It goes in activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Can I use something other than a fixed 150dp size to set the height of
>    the navbar? (such as a percentage)

for this i use

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >
        <Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGreen2"
            android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
        

        </Toolbar>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This text is underneath"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this and it doesn't fix the issue. The issue is that to the left of the textview is a blank area. I want there to be no blank area. See image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTeMt.png .

Comment: add layout_gravity left to the textview

Comment: Didn't work. I want the text to be underneath the navigation bar button.

Comment: seems like i had missed a closing tag, that should work

Comment: The code you wrote makes a toolbar with a textview underneath it. I want the textView to be inside the toolbar and underneath the navigation hamburger button. The original code does that, however when I add the navigation bar button, a margin appears underneath the button. Please see the image of my activity currently here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E1Wf.png . Notice the margin on the left underneath the navigation bar button. I would like to remove that margin so that the final project looks like this(edited in photoshop) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTeMt.png